# Backup Mantis

Tags: sql, issue-tracking, mantis

I want to fully backup my Mantis tracking system, what is the easiest way to do this?
If I only backup the database, does it backup everything on Mantis already?

Thanks!!

Comment: This question is perhaps more suited to the Mantis support forums.  It's not related to programming either.

Comment: yes, but here should get much faster response, also many topics have its own official forum too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To completely backup Mantis, the database state must be saved. In addition, you should back up the following files or directories:

- the upload directory, if Mantis is configured to store attachments on disk;
- the config_inc.php file
- any other custom files, like custom_strings_inc.php or custom_constant_inc.php

Comment: sorry for late reply. Where should I find the 'upload' folder? Also, I can't find the 'custom_strings_inc.php' file, where is it located?  Thanks.

Comment: If there's no custom_strings_inc.php file, there's nothing to backup. The upload folder should exist if `$g_file_upload_method` is set to `DISK`

Comment: The 'upload' folder should be stored in './mantis/' folder, right?? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think so ( I don't use disk uploads )

Comment: Thanks, I checked the 'config_inc.php' file, but I can't find the '$g_file_upload_method' option, what is the default setting?

Comment: Sorry, I just found in config_default_inc.php, it is set to:  $g_file_upload_method = DATABASE, so upload folder shouldn't exist, right?

Comment: Yes, if you save attachments to the db there's no upload folder.